# Unpacking a vector into a list with each element of vector as separate elements in list

Tags: r, list, concatenation

With the following code, I am creating a list:

```
scales <- c(p="hye", r="t3")
details <- list(t=20,y="c", scales)
```

At the moment the above gives me a list as so:

```
$t
[1] 20

$y  
[1] "c"

[[3]]
p     r 
"hye"  "t3"
```

However I want a list like so:

```
$t
[1] 20

$y  
[1] "c"

$p      
[1] "hye"  

$r
[1] "t3"
```

Since this is going to be reused in a function I want to keep `scales` as a vector argument that I can then insert into a list. How can I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The solution is:

```
details = c(list(t=20,y="c"),scales)
```

Comment: You might want to make the Answer more of a statement than a comment/question. Doesn't invoke confidence if you aren't sure it works - which it does. +1 for not needing the `as.list()`..

Comment: "Does this work?" was meant to be rhetorical, as in "Is this the solution you're looking for?" Good point though. I'll be more forthright in future :)

Answer (score 3):

You want to concatenate vis `c()` two lists, so use `as.list()` to convert the `scales` vector into a list before forming `details`:

```
> details <- c(list(t=20, y="c"), as.list(scales))
> details
$t
[1] 20

$y
[1] "c"

$p
[1] "hye"

$r
[1] "t3"
```

Comment: That seems more logical but @TimP 's also works (without explicit `as.list`) plus answered first so I'll accept that answer.Thanks though

Comment: Cool. Yeah, no need for `as.list` here since the result of the `c()` will be a list anyway.

Comment: @TimP Duplicate yes, almost, but not intentional; we were working on these at the same time - it does happen.